# SVG image pattern doesn't work on Safari

Tags: google-chrome, svg, safari

I have a svg shape that I filled with a background image with the following

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="circle" x="-50%" y="-50%" height="200%" width="500%" viewBox="0 0 750 750">
        <image x="0%" y="0%" width="750" height="750" href="image.png"></image>
    </pattern>
</defs>
<path fill="url(#circle)" id="XMLID_22_" d="M561.8 396.7c0 44.6-36.1 80.7-80.7 80.7-44.5 0-80.7-36.1-80.7-80.7 0-44.5 36.1-80.7 80.7-80.7s80.7 36.1 80.7 80.7z"/>
```

It works with charm on Chrome but not on Safari, nothing is displayed at all

Comment: Yes thanks that was the solution!

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Safari doesn't support href, you need to use xlink:href there. href is a new feature of the upcoming SVG 2 specification. xlink:href is the SVG 1.1 version.

Answer (score 0):

for Safari to process the svg image pattern, I've learned that you need three things:
1) make sure you use xlink:href  as stated above.
2) your pattern/image has to have width and height in pixels.  Chrome doesn't demand this, And you already have this.  I'm just mentioning it b/c it was one of the things I had to change for mine to work.
3) your reference to the url has to be complete:
fill=`url(`+ window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + `#circle`